# How to process async response from WebClient?

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux

I'm trying to use WebClient to make massive Http POST request.
I put the logging level on `reactor.ipc.netty` to DEBUG to see the request being sent.

Here is a functioning code :

```
@Service
public class HttpService implements IHttpService {

    private static final String URL = "http://blablabla.com/bla";

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();

    @Autowired
    WebClient webClient;

    @Override
    public void push(Data data) {
        String body = constructString(data);
        Mono<ClientResponse> res = webClient.post()
                .uri(URL + getLogType(data))
                .contentLength(body.length())
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .syncBody(body)
                .exchange();
        ClientResponse resp = res.block();
        logger.debug("Status : " + resp.statusCode());
        logger.debug("Body : " + resp.bodyToMono(String.class));
    }
}
```

It produces that kind of log :

```
2018-05-16 15:54:14.642 DEBUG 19144 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] r.i.n.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler   : [id: 0x439f7819, L:/127.0.0.1:56556 - R:blablabla.com/127.0.0.1:8069] Writing object DefaultHttpRequest(decodeResult: success, version: HTTP/1.1)
POST /bla HTTP/1.1
user-agent: ReactorNetty/0.7.7.RELEASE
host: blablabla.com/bla:8069
accept: */*
accept-encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 494
Content-Type: application/json
```

But when I delete `ClientResponse resp = res.block();` I don't see the log anymore... So I don't even know if the request is processed or not.
How can I process the response as soon as I get it ?
I tried with `res.doOnSuccess(clientResponse -> logger.debug("Code : " + clientResponse.statusCode()));` but with no success...

Comment: When I'm not waiting for the response anymore

Comment: Are you subscribing to your res? It won't action unless there is a subscriber e.g. res.subscribe(clientResponse -> System.out.println("res.statusCode() = " + clientResponse.statusCode())); by calling block are are explicitly waiting for it to execute, ... doOnsuccess is printing for me after subscribe

Comment: No I wasn't subscribing to it... I tried and it works fine ! thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `Flux` and `Mono` are Reactive Streams types, they are also lazy: nothing happens until you `subscribe` to it. There are several methods that can achieve that goal, and `subscribe` or `block` are amongst those.

Usually, Spring WebFlux applications don't `subscribe` directly and actually return those reactive types; without more context in your case, I can't really say what would be the right approach here.

Check out the [Reactor project reference documentation on `Flux` and `Mono`](http://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#core-features), this should help you understand the core principles behind this.